# How to display to client the model exception message when an exception is thrown in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In controller suppose I get some Student instances from some method. I get them from DB and then I create instances for each record. But in model class I have some validation to don't allow instance creation if the parameters are not valid. The problem is that I want to display the exception thrown message as an alert, or any view.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You don't want to show exception details to an end user as this exposes implementation details of your application, which in itself introduces [security risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Exception_Handling#Displaying_Errors).

Comment: Please specify what you want with your code eample

Comment: If you do nothing, the user WILL see your exception and the stack trace.  It might not be in a user friendly manner, but your users shouldn't see this. In a production environment IIS will hide this and return a 500 (which is what you want).